# Can not create bean of 'firestoreTemplate'

Tags: java, spring, firebase, spring-boot, google-cloud-firestore

When I try to run my application, I get this error, `Field textbookRepository in com.uga.backend.controller.TextbookController required a bean named 'firestoreTemplate' that could not be found.` No matter what I have tried I get this error, from my understanding the `firestoreTemplate` bean should be a valid candidate for the `@Autowired` decorator because I set up my firebase configurations correctly in application.properties and I'm using the `@EnableFirestoreReactiveRepositories` decorator in the main class, but so far there has been no luck, would love to see if anyone here could help me out. There doesn't seem to be a way to manually create a bean the for firestoreTemplate either or at least I have not been able to find a way yet. Here is the rest of my code

**TextbookRepository.java**

```
package com.uga.backend.repository;


import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.data.firestore.FirestoreReactiveRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.uga.backend.entity.Textbook;

@Repository("textbookRepository")
public interface TextbookRepository extends FirestoreReactiveRepository<Textbook> {

}
```

**TextbookController.java**

```
package com.uga.backend.controller;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.uga.backend.entity.Textbook;
import com.uga.backend.repository.TextbookRepository;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/textbooks")
public class TextbookController {

    @Autowired
    TextbookRepository textbookRepository;

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public Mono<Textbook> save(@RequestBody Textbook textbook) {
        return this.textbookRepository.save(textbook);
    }

    @GetMapping("/get")
    public Mono<Textbook> getById(@RequestParam String id) {
        return this.textbookRepository.findById(id);
    }

    @GetMapping("/getAll")
    public Flux<Textbook> getAll() {
        return this.textbookRepository.findAll();
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/delete")
    public Mono<Void> delete(String id) {
        return this.textbookRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

}
```

**BackendApplication.java**

```
package com.uga.backend;


import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.data.firestore.repository.config.EnableReactiveFirestoreRepositories;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableReactiveFirestoreRepositories("com.uga.backend.repository")
@ComponentScan("com.uga.backend.controllers")
public class BackendApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BackendApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.cloud.gcp.firestore.project-id=project-id
spring.cloud.gcp.firestore.credentials.location=file:./serviceAccount.json
spring.cloud.gcp.firestore.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gcp.firestore.auto-create-indices=true
```

Comment: [You should not *force* a tag into your title.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) Because the tags appear below the question and tags are indexed by search engines along with the content of your question, you can trust that other people will be able to find your question based on tags they follow or search for.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-data-firestore</artifactId>
    <version>${your.version}</version>
 </dependency>
```

It will help to autoconfigure all necessary beans.

You can also remove `@EnableReactiveFirestoreRepositories` because `FirestoreReactiveRepository` is extended in repository instance and it detects as a repository automatically as well.

Comment: that repo was not updated for 2 years. he should use 

com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies, com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-data-firestore and com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure instead